# Create table if not exists from mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if there is any way in mysqldump to add the appropriate create table option [IF NOT EXISTS]. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [one source](http://www.mail-archive.com/mysql@lists.mysql.com/msg55422.html), mysqldump does not feature this option.

You could use the `--force` option when importing the dump file back, where MySQL will ignore the errors generated from attempts to create duplicate tables. However note that with this method, other errors would be ignored as well.

Otherwise, you can run your dump file through a script that would replace all occurrences of `CREATE TABLE` with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 36):

Try to use this on your SQL file:

```
sed 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' <file-path>
```

or to save

```
sed -i 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' <file-path>
```

it's not ideal but it works :P

Comment: Hopefully there is no data in your db with that specific string in it. :)

Comment: You could mitigate errors by expanding the match, `$ sed 's/^CREATE TABLE foo/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo/g'`

Comment: might want to mention that on macos it's `sed -i '' 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' <file-path>` where the single quotes after -i are for the back up extension

Answer (score 18):

Using `sed` as described by @Pawel works well. Nevertheless you might not like the idea of piping your data through more potential error sources than absolutely necessary. In this case one may use two separate dumps:

- first dump containing table definitions (`--no-data --skip-add-drop-table`)
- second dump with only data (`--no-create-info --skip-add-drop-table`)

There are some other things to take care of though (e.g. triggers). Check the manual for details.

Answer (score 9):

Not what you might want, but with `--add-drop-table` every CREATE is prefixed with the according DROP TABLE statement.

Otherwise, I'd go for a simple search/replace (e.g., with `sed`).

Answer (score 6):

The dump output is the combination of DROP and CREATE, so you must remove DROP statement and change the CREATE statement to form a valid (logical) output:

```
 mysqldump --no-data -u root <schema> | sed 's/^CREATE TABLE /CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS /'| sed 's/^DROP TABLE IF EXISTS /-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS /' > <schema>.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a bash script with this. E.g. dump.sh `touch dump.sh`

Make sure you make it executable: `chmod 0750 dump.sh`

dump.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="mysqldump_${HOSTNAME}_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M').sql"
echo "Using filename: ${name}"
mysqldump --replace --skip-add-drop-table --skip-comments izon -p > "${name}"
sed -i 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' "${name}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The sed will be **much** faster without the 'g' (global) at its end:

eg:

```
mysqldump -e <database> | sed 's/^CREATE TABLE /CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS /' > <database>.sql
```

Comment: If you want the final SQL works, you must remove DROP TABLE IF EXIST too.

Answer (score 0):

To Find and replace the text **On Windows 7 Using PowerShell**

Open command prompt and use the command below

```
powershell -Command "(gc E:\map\map_2017.sql) -replace 'CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS' | Out-File E:\map\map_replaced.sql"
```

- First param is the filepath
- Second param is 'find string'
- Third param is 'replace string'

This command will create a new file with the replaced text.
Remove the Command starting from '|' (pipe) if you want to replace and save contents on the same file.