# MySQL SHOW CREATE TABLE parameters?

Tags: mysql

I am using the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command to get a create code for my table. However, I noticed that the create command is missing a few features.

For instance, it doesn't have an `IF NOT EXISTS` parameter. It also lists the `AUTO_INCREMENT=#` position at the end; which isn't really needed since its an auto increment.

Is there any way to add parameters to the query to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahhh...simple...no, you can't. [Check docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think your more interested in mysql dump that does include more information.

However, specifically for the "if not exists", you will have to replace that using a script or grep.

**References:**

[Create table if not exists from mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220469/create-table-if-not-exists-from-mysqldump)