# mysql dump create if not exists option

Tags: exec, mysql, create-table

Here is my current command;

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password --host=example.com --add-drop-table=FALSE DATABASENAME > /tmp/sql_file.sql
```

I want an extra option to insert the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` on each table. I still want the `DROP TABLE` turned off and I don't want a straight forward `CREATE TABLE` command as sometimes the tables might already exist - and sometimes not.

Can I do this?

So far this command will include a `CREATE TABLE` and then I get an error because the table already exists.

I have also tried `--no-create-info` but that, unsurprisingly, didn't even give me `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: try removing --add-drop-table=FALSE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220469/create-table-if-not-exists-from-mysqldump

Comment: Duplicate from [Create table if not exists from mysqldump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220469/create-table-if-not-exists-from-mysqldump)